# Portable Database for Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio

I have been using SQL CE for a desktop app I am building but the limitations of it may not make it the best option for me so I am looking for an alternative.

Requirements:
-Need to easily be able to utilize in Visual Studio
-Portable as this will get installed on numerous client machines
-Don't want to install XAMPP, for example and all the other stuff that comes with it.  Single File I can include in the install would be ideal that my tool can communicate with.
-The potential is there to have the database be larger than 4 gig. 
-need to be able to add images to the database.

I was looking at MYSQL as a possibility but I don't know much about it and I don't see that there is a portable version.  All the versions require me to do some sort of install on a client machine.

I like SQL CE but 4 gig limitation i didn't like as well as not being able to easily create views.(This could be that I don't know how to use it well enough but I wasn't able to save queries and the only way i have seen that I can get data that I need is through code and I would rather avoid this if at all possible)

Anyone know of a good portable database out there that might meet my needs?

Comment: What are the requirements? Over 4GB size limit, but what about multi-user? Are you willing to pay for a technology?

Comment: SQL CE 4 meets most of your requirements.. support by VSSP1 .. **with** the 4GB limit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689403/the-limit-of-sql-ce-4-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) which have embedded version

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server. It is ideal for
>   CDROM catalogs, demos or standalone
>   desktop applications.

Comment: I will take a peak at firebird.  thanks for all the responses.