# Lightweight SQL database with strong typing and no size limit

Tags: .net, database, xcopy

I'm looking for a lightweight SQL database engine that can run in the same process as the .NET application I'm developing, no other installation required. I know of two options:

1. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
2. [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

At first glance these are pretty good options for me because they support most of the advanced features I need (such as concurrency, transactions, etc) without requiring a separate database server installation. However they each have a major downside:

1. SQLite uses dynamic typing which means [no errors will be thrown if you try to insert the wrong data type into a column](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3). The extra data validation is half the reason I'm using a database in the first place.
2. SQL Server CE has a [4 GB size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689678/138757).

Are there any other database engines that can be used in a .NET context which can be "xcopy" deployed?

Comment: Does the database have to be relational ?

Comment: Dynamically typed doesn't mean weakly typed, what it does mean is, you need good unit tests. An ORM would take care of most of your typing difficulties.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson For the most part I agree. However it's likely people will be accessing this database from outside my software, which means I won't have control over all the code that's running against the DB. Also if a random bug _somehow_ makes it into production, I want the database to catch it. Extra layer of safety.

Comment: @Phil. Agreed If you don't have control over access to the SqlLite db, then it's not an option.

Comment: When you say other code will be running against the db, this is on the same machine right? Neither one is good solution if remote access is involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/start/) fulfill all wanted requirements, and it has native .NET driver

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/development-net-provider/